# STL on time series with missing values for anomaly detection

Tags: r, time-series, outliers, missing-data

I am trying to detect anomalous values in a time series of climatic data with some missing observations. Searching the web I found many available approaches. Of those, stl decomposition seems appealing, in the sense of removing trend and seasonal components and studying the remainder. Reading [STL: A Seasonal-Trend Decomposition Procedure Based on Loess](http://www.wessa.net/download/stl.pdf), `stl` appears to be flexible in determining the settings for assigning variability, unaffected by outliers and possible to apply despite missing values. However, trying to apply it in `R`, with four years of observations and defining all the parameters according to http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/stl.html , I encounter error:

`"time series contains internal NAs"` (when `na.action=na.omit`), and
`"series is not periodic or has less than two periods"` (when `na.action=na.exclude`).

I have double checked that the frequency is correctly defined. I have seen relevant questions in blogs, but didn't find any suggestion that could solve this. Is it not possible to apply `stl` in a series with missing values? I am very reluctant to interpolate them, as I do not want to be introducing (and consequently detecting...) artifacts. For the same reason, I do not know how advisable it would be to use ARIMA approaches instead (and if missing values would still be a problem).

Please share if you know a way to apply `stl` in a series with missing values, or if you believe my choices are methodologically not sound, or if you have any better suggestion. I am quite new in the field and overwhelmed by the heaps of (seemingly...) relevant information.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. STL method should be able to just fill in the missing values thru LOESS, but this R implementation does not seems to do so.

Answer (score 5):

ARIMA models easily incorporate dummy variables to deal with missing values. These are called Pulse Indicators . The methodology is straightforward and documented in http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf. In general the method extracts from the current residual series information regarding Pulses, Level Shifts, Seasonal Pulses and Local Time Trends.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion and the very interesting article!

Answer (score 4):

According to @Julius in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14616460/2824732) is it possible to use `stl` with `na.approx`, from `zoo` package, using `stl(x, na.action = na.approx, ...)`. This does some sort of [interpolation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/na.approx).

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out [Hafen's `stlplus` package](https://github.com/hafen/stlplus). Details are in his thesis.

You can install it from CRAN with

```
install.packages("stlplus")
```

or directly from github with

```
devtools::install_github("hafen/stlplus").
```